# Which are Tarantino’s eight films?

Tags: quentin-tarantino, the-hateful-eight

*The Hateful Eight* is an upcoming film by Quentin Tarantino.

I remember reading somewhere that the title is a reference to not only the
characters in the film, but also to this being his eighth movie. Is this true and if so, what are the eight movies?

Comment: Well, if you count *Kill Bill* as one movie (and *Deathproof* as a standalone), [this would be his 8th film](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000233/).

Comment: What about Dusk til Dawn? .....

Comment: Wasn't True Romance also by him?

Comment: @user28813 Only written by him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> THE 8TH FILM FROM QUENTIN TARANTINO

[image: Poster of "The Hateful Eight", "The 8th Film from Quentin Tarantino".]

These appear to be the eight:

1. Reservoir Dogs (1992)
2. Pulp Fiction (1994)
3. Jackie Brown (1997)
4. Kill Bill (2003)
5. Death Proof (2007)
6. Inglourious Basterds (2009)
7. Django Unchained (2012)
8. The Hateful Eight (2015)

[Source](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Tarantino#Filmography)

Answer (score 50):

The problem with Tarantino movies is that they have been 'misused' when they were released.

- ***Kill Bill*** was originally scheduled for a single theatrical release, but with a running time of over four hours it was split into two parts by the [Weinstein Brothers](http://www.hollywood.com/news/brief/1722113/tarantino-s-kill-bill-split-into-two-parts). However, it was written, shot, and edited as one big movie.
- ***Grindhouse*** was also meant to be one movie, but after an unsuccessful opening weekend the movie was split into two parts. Again by the [Weinstein Brothers](http://www.slashfilm.com/grindhouse-to-be-split-into-2-movies/) The single parts (***Death Proof*** and ***Planet Terror***) that were released were extended.

#### Directing credits

Tarantino has also some credits as director in movies that are not fully his own.

- ***Sin City*** has only one scene in the entire movie that is directed by him. You can view it on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_CuAzFt664). This is a copy of the comic book so I can understand why they don't call this a Tarantino movie.
- There is also a movie called ***Four Rooms***. It is what they call an omnibus movie where several directors work with a specific theme, in this example the adventures of a bell boy. Tarantino's segment is only 25 minutes long so again, not a movie that is entirely his.

IMDb lists ***Love Birds in Bondage*** and ***My Best Friend's Birthday*** but they were reportedly lost in a fire according to the IMDB trivia page. However, there are some sources that say that the movies were never finished. In any way: these are not movies worth advertising since they don't exist or haven't been viewed in almost 30 years.

IMDb also lists two directing credits for **CSI** and for **E.R.** but these are episodes of television shows.

#### Writing credits

And while he was involved in the scenarios of ***From Dusk Till Dawn***, ***True Romance***, and ***Natural Born Killers***, he didn't direct those movies.

#### The final list

1. ***[Reservoir Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_Dogs)***
2. ***[Pulp Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_Fiction)***
3. ***[Jackie Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Brown_(film))***
4. ***[Kill Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_Bill)*** (1 and 2)
5. ***[Grindhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grindhouse_(film))*** (or you could place ***Death Proof*** here)
6. ***[Inglourious Basterds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglourious_Basterds)***
7. ***[Django Unchained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_Unchained)***
8. ***[The Hateful Eight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hateful_Eight)***

Answer (score -3):

The eight Tarantino movies are:

1: Reservoir dogs
2: Pulp Fiction
3: Jackie brown
4: Kill bill 
5: Death proof
6: Inglorious basterds
7: Django Unchained
8: The hateful eight

Comment: wrong. he directed, produced, wrote and filmed death proof. its one of the eight. period

Comment: Death proof is a part of the double feature"Grindhouse",also featuring Robert rodriguez

Comment: Death proof would have been one of the eight if it were a single feature

Comment: Death Proof _was_ released as a single feature.  After the initial Grindhouse release, the two films were extended with additional scenes and released as separate works.  Thus, Death Proof became a separate film in its own right, and is counted as one of Tarantino's films.

Comment: Also, Kill Bill was originally a single film, so is counted in the Tarantino canon as being one film that was released in two parts.