# Why is The Hateful Eight billed as Tarantino's Eighth movie?

Tags: quentin-tarantino, the-hateful-eight

As far as movies he's directed, I count at least ten (in no particular order):

1. Reservoir Dogs
2. Pulp Fiction
3. Jackie Brown
4. Kill Bill vol. 1
5. Kill Bill vol. 2
6. Four Rooms
7. Grindhouse
8. Django Unchained
9. Inglorious Bastards
10. My Best Friend's Birthday

In addition, he's written screenplays for From Dusk Till Dawn, True Romance and Natural Born Killers. I count at least 12 (with Kill Bill 1 & 2 being counted as the same movies. I won't even get into acting credits...

Why the bad math?

Comment: Related: [Which are Tarantino’s eight films?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33028/49)

Comment: That older question is a bit less in depth and more trivial. But the top answer seems to adress your specific doubts. So I'd still be inclined to call that pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: I feel like that other question is asking for a list of the "eight" movies. My question is asking for a little more: Why are his other movies not being counted?

Comment: Indeed. But on the other hand, the top-answer perfectly adresses this.

Comment: I've updated http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/33033/13595 with information about the movies he was involved with as a writer. Obviously movies where he is merely credited as an actor cannot be considered "Tarantino movies".

Comment: @BCdotWEB why not count movies he acted in? My logic: Marilyn Monroe never directed a movie, but there are many "Marilyn Monroe movies".

Comment: @BenPlont The poster says "the 8th movie ***from*** Tarantino", i.e. written and directed by Tarantino. Also, you cannot seriously argue that a movie that features Tarantino as an actor is a Tarantino movie.