# Is it a coincidence that Tarantino’s eighth film has “Eight" in the title?

Tags: title, quentin-tarantino, the-hateful-eight

Quentin Tarantino is known for caring about the numbering of his films. Going by his own numbering, which counts Kill Bill as a single movie, The Hateful Eight is his eighth film. Has he ever said whether he intentionally picked a name with “eight” in the title, or waited until his eighth film to make that movie, or if it is just a coincidence?

Coincidence seems unlikely, given his attention to detail and use of references throughout his films. But as a second part to the question, if he did title the movie in honor of it being his eighth film, did he also write the script to fit that number in the title?

Comment: More interestingly, why would his eighth film be hateful?

Comment: I also just noticed that this is (I believe) the first of his films to actually include the numbering within the film itself; the other ones had it in the trailers but only said “a film by Quentin Tarantino” during the actual opening credits.

Comment: Related: [Which are Tarantino’s eight films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33028/1006)

Comment: One possibly-relevant fact is that Chinese culture traditionally holds that 8 is a very lucky number. IIRC, someone in China even spent a small fortune for the vanity license plate "888". I'm sure QT is familiar with this aspect of Chinese/Asian cluture, and it possibly motivated him to double-up his 8s when it was convenient. Per Pascal: it can't hurt.